# Retrieve value from array of dictionary : Python

Tags: python, abaqus

I have the below as output from an application which I am trying to customize using Python.

```
({'featureName': 'Solid extrude-1', 'index': 6, 'instanceName': None, 'isReferenceRep': False, 'pointOn': ((-71.25, 18.75, 20.0),)})
```

I want to get the Coordinate values ( `'pointOn'` key) from this variable.

I am not sure if this is array of dictionary or something else.

Comment: Is the application outputting this string from a print command? It looks like the string output of a python tuple.

Comment: Yes, I am getting this after doing a print of the variable which is passed from the application.

Comment: Something's not quite right, because if the variable you are printing is a tuple there should be a comma before the end paren. If it isn't a tuple, where do the parenthesis come from?

Comment: @jme fair point. Try using type() on the app output to see what it is; might just be a poorly formatted string.

Comment: I tried print Point1[0]['pointOn']  and got the below :TypeError : 'InterestingPoint' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you got is actually an object. Abaqus just overwrites implementation of `__str__` method, so that output looks like something else.

If your object is assigned to name `Point1`, try accessing members in the following way:

```
Point1.pointOn
Point1.featureName
```

In general, Abaqus usually either returns a repository (collection) of objects or a single objects. Rarely can you get something other than that.